# Cannot provide chart as a parameter for youtube search API

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-data-api

I try to get youtube trending by country, based on [youtube search API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list), I can set chart to 'mostPopular' which was supposed to return the trending video details, but it didn't work, and  returned an error

[image]

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

DEVELOPER_KEY = "XXXXXXXXX"
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"


def youtube_search(max_results=5, order="relevance", token=None, location=None, location_radius=None,
                   regionCode=None):
    youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION, developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)

    search_response = youtube.search().list(
        type="video",
        pageToken=token,
        order=order,
        part="id,snippet",  # Part signifies the different types of data you want
        chart="mostPopular",
        maxResults=max_results,
        location=location,
        locationRadius=location_radius,
        regionCode = regionCode,
        ).execute()

    print(search_response)

youtube_search(regionCode='IE')
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chart is a parameter on the [Videos resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list), it is not available on the Search resource.